# Establishing isomorphism between groups using their invariant matrices

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, group-isomorphism

I want to show that the groups $Sp(2,R)$ and $SU(1,1)$ are isomorphic.
But more generally I wonder, if two groups $G_1, G_2$ leave the matrices $M_1, M_2 $ invariant respectively.
Then can I show an isomorphism between the groups if I show $$SM_1S^{\dagger}=M_2.$$
Where $S$ is a unitary matrix.

More specifically $Sp(2,R)$ and $SU(1,1)$ leave,
$$        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 \\
        -1 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 \\
        \end{pmatrix},
$$
invariant, respectively. This is what I have been led to believe but I am not sure why it would be true. Is it? Or is there an easier alternative way of showing isomorphism in this case?

Comment: I have realized that there exists no such $S$ since 1, -1 are not the eigenvalues of $M_1$. Any help would still be appreciated.